# Project references are not resolved after updating NuGet packges through CLI

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a nightly process running on `TeamCity` that will loop through my packages on a locally hosted `NuGet repo` and update all packages in all solutions to the latest `prerelease version`.

When I pull the latest code the morning after. The solution builds fine, but my project references are not loaded.

**Unresolved project references:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpxJO.jpg

**Unresolved code:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/aip4T.jpg

I'm using `packages.config` to manage my NuGet packages. 
In order to continue working I have to "reload" my *Visual Studio projects* by either manually asking the properties of the missing reference, or by changing something in the `.csproj` file. 
That is my little workaround, but for some solutions with 10+ projects this becomes quite cumbersome.

Other means of updating packages work fine, if I try to update the packages through Visual Studio I have no issues. It only fails when using the NuGet.exe command line utility.

Here's the command we use to update the packages through `NuGet.exe` on `TeamCity` during a nightly build:

`NuGet.exe update <path_to_packages.config> -Id <current_package_to_update> -pre -NonInteractive`

This is the **version of NuGet** we're using:
`NuGet Version: 4.8.1.5435`

Here's an excerpt of the logging:

```
found  PFW.Utilities  with version  2019.9.0-build0009  in file  C:\Sources\Xmp\ModXmp\packages.config
http://srvppratonexus.prato.be:8888/nexus/service/rest/repository/browse/nuget-prato-prereleases/PFW.Utilities/2019.9.0-build0009
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '16.1.76.45076' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin'.
```

**Feeds used:**

```
  http://srvppratonexus:8888/nexus/service/local/nuget/nuget-group/
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for multiple packages with respect to project `C:\Sources\Xmp\ModXmp\ModXmp.csproj`, targeting `.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1`


Gathering dependency information took 10.79 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions install multiple packages
Found package 'PFW.Utilities 2019.9.0-build0019' in 'C:\Sources\Xmp\packages'.
Removed package 'PFW.Utilities 2019.9.0-build0009' from 'packages.config'
Successfully uninstalled 'PFW.Utilities 2019.9.0-build0009' from ModXmp
Package 'PFW.Utilities.2019.9.0-build0019' already exists in folder 'C:\Sources\Xmp\packages'
Added package 'PFW.Utilities.2019.9.0-build0019' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'PFW.Utilities 2019.9.0-build0019' to ModXmp
Executing nuget actions took 192.26 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I pull the latest code the morning after. The solution builds
>   fine, but my project references are not loaded.

When you call `nuget.exe` to update `nuget packages` for the project using packages.config format outside the VS IDE, it not only modified the `packages.config` file, but also modified the `project file(.csproj)`. So VS IDE can't load them well unless a reload.

Not sure what's the real solution you have, you can `Go Tools => option => Environment => Documents`, make sure you've enabled the `Detect when file is changed outside the environment`. Then you can get **reload all** dialog when you modify the project file outside VS IDE.

**Reload all** dialog looks like this:

[image]

> That is my little workaround, but for some solutions with 10+ projects
>   this becomes quite cumbersome.

If for some reason that dialog didn't occur, you can manually open one .csproj using notepad, then add one empty line into it and save. VS will detect the change and show the dialog, then click reload all to reload all projects in the solution.(For the solution with many projects)

Comment: As you suggested, reloading works as intended and changing the .csproj file manually as well.
However, my Visual Studio instance is not open while the nuget packages have been updated. I open Visual Studio, start the solution, restore my packages and lo and behold the references are not loaded.

Comment: @WeyensL I'm confused that when the solution is open is VS  ,do you get the `reload all` dialog when you use nuget command outside VS to modify the .csproj? The reload is necessary in this situation since when we do changes to project file outside VS, we have to reload them to refresh the UI and other things.